# Need to create a specific workOrder when Maintaince Plan is created

Tags: fields, fls, sales, work-order

I need help with some stuff, I need to create suppose 5 workOrder when the Maintain Plan is created via APEX ?

When i access it's field's via apex it give me error.

I have the Field Level Access (Confirmed).

/*Standard Solution*/

I know Salesforce provide you functionality to create records via Auto/Manual Where can i configure based on input that on Maintain plan that this much work order's  need to generated

Comment: so, what error do you get? ; please see [ask] and make your change using [edit]

Comment: I'm not sure I undestood your question. Do you want to create the records via Apex or Process Builder? If you plan to create it using an Apex class can you please detail the error you are retrieving?

Comment: I was getting the error the field is not writeable AccountID on Appointments